# Mastering Oracle Trace Data - Page 60: APEX Tracing URL Extension

Tags: oracle

I have a question regarding the APEX tracing section on page 60 of [The Method R Guide to Mastering Oracle Trace Data](https://method-r.com/2016/05/20/motd2/).

"Many great window-on-data applications these days are developed with Oracle Application Express (APEX). Tracing is easy in APEX. The simplest tracing operation, tracing a single page execution, is trivially easy to do: simply append `&p_trace=YES` to the page’s URL."

I do not work with APEX a lot, but needed to trace APEX applications (APEX 4.x) from time to time. Unfortunately it never worked out with the URL extension even if I did the exact same procedure you described in the book. Later on I discovered that maybe the debug mode must be activated as well to get this running (slide 13: http://www.aioug.org/sangam12/Presentations/20157.pdf). However I always needed to edit the APEX header and footer page to enable/disable tracing.

Any idea what I am missing here? Is debug mode needed even if not mentioned in the book?

Thank you.

Regards
Stefan

P.S.: In addition maybe you guys also know an extension or clever way to implement DBMS_PROFILER on APEX pages to get the complete hierarchy (https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Oracle-APEX-4x-Looking-for-clever-ways-to-implement-DBMS-PROFILER)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional debug mode information is present in [The Method R Guide to Mastering Oracle Trace Data, 2nd Edition](https://method-r.com/2016/05/20/motd2/) printings with a revised date of August 4, 2016 or later.

The following answer comes from our colleague Doug Gault.

To enable the `&P_TRACE` appended to the URL, the following things need to be true:

1. Trace must be enabled at the APEX instance level.
2. Debug must be enabled at the application level.

In early versions of APEX, debugging being enabled was not a prerequisite for tracing. This was added somewhere in the lifecycle of APEX 4 to protect against someone writing scripts to append that to every call and filling up your file system.

I do know that in certain versions of 4.X, there were issues where this did not work as expected. The issues were addressed (I believe) in 4.2.5 and should be available and working from that point forward.

A little known fact of the `P_TRACE` parameter is that there are actually three settings available: `YES`, `TRACE`, and `HPROF`.

The first two basically do the same thing—turn on event 10046 tracing. However, if you use `HPROF` as the value of the parameter, APEX will use the Hierarchical Profiler.

There is also an instance level parameter `HPROF_DIRECTORY` that can be set by a DBA by calling `apex_instance_admin.set_parameter`.

Comment: The HPROF value for p_trace is not documented and hence not supported. To my knowledge it couldn't be made public due to some unresolved bugs or inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: A good place in APEX to enable/disable trace or profiling can be found under Shared Components / Security Attributes / Database session in the "Initialization PL/SQL Code" and "Cleanup PL/SQL Code" blocks. On top of that APEX 5.2 will bring a new API method: APEX_SESSION.Set_Trace to activate trace for a remote user session.

Answer (score 0):

At least this was the missing piece for me:

I suspected that internally Apex creates the .trc file by using

```
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level xx';
```

Depending on how the Schema (that Apex is working with) has been created this priv is missing. I was able to let Oracle write a trc file by granting the schema the "alter session" priv...

```
grant alter session to apex_demo;
```

Hope that helps.

Best,
Jonas